# Save the list of urls which is showing error in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am new in jmeter, and I got a task to save the urls in a file which is showing error after running the script.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

The easiest way is to add the next line to *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
```

or pass it via `-J` command line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.url=true -n -t script.jmx -l results.jtl
```

You will get results like:

[image: CSV with URL]

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of working with them.

---

**Option 2:**

If you need to store URLs separately - use a [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners), for example [Simple Data Writer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) configured like:

[image: Simple Data Writer]

---

**Option 3:**

If for any reason you need to do it in Beanshell:

1. Add [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) to your Test Plan
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

   if (!sampleResult.isSuccessful()) {
     FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("errors.txt"), sampleResult.getUrlAsString() + System.getProperty("line.separator"),true);  
   }
   ```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on using Beanshell test elements in JMeter tests.